# jQuery - Detect if user can see the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, detect

Well, the title says enough, **jQuery - Detect if user can see the bottom of the page**.

Important though is that I have to know it on page load.

So **not** *"Has the user **scrolled** down to bottom of page?"*.
Of course, JavaScript answer is fine :).

*P.S. Isn't it weird that there isn't a tag "Page"?*

EDIT: Isn't there like a variable where you can get the page height (regardless of the browser) and the window height (that the browser sees)?
Then you could just use

```
if(window.height() < page.height()){
   //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying like this:-

```
if (($("#div").offset().top + $("#div").height()) >= $(window).height()) 
{
  //....
}
```

**EDIT:-**

Try this:-

```
 if($(document).height()>$(window).height())
```

Comment: That didn't work (maybe it's relevant to tell I used a footer div for your code). Though, see my updated question,

Comment: Try using:-  if($(document).height()>$(window).height())

Comment: May be this:- if($(document).height()-$(window).height() == 0). Although thats really strange!! :)